# Handling Camera-Style Mouse Movement in Javascript (enabling continuous mouse movement)

Tags: javascript, mouse, handler, webgl

**The idea:** I'm creating a simple WebGL script (using mrdoob's wonderful three.js) that allows the user to control a camera in a world of objects. The camera is supposed to simulate traditional first person shooter cameras (reference Team Fortress 2, for example). That is, the camera moves only when the mouse moves.

**The issue:** in Javascript, the only way to detect mouse movement is if the cursor itself moves. By comparison, FPS games don't show the cursor -- they only base the movement of the camera off of how the mouse itself moves. So, you can move your mouse all over the mousepad in any direction and it always works.

On a browser though, since camera movement is based on the cursor, you can't move but so far. When the cursor hits the edge of the screen, the user is unable to look any further in that direction (e.g. you move your mouse to the left edge of the screen, you can't look left any more).

**The solution:** I've thought of two solutions, but neither of which I know how to implement. Either

1. After the mouse is moved, the javascript resets it to the center of the screen. That way, after every mouse movement the player is free to again move in any direction. The issue with this is that, based on the research I've done, Javascript is unable to control the position of the user's mouse (understandably, as it would be an incomparable nuisance on malignant sites).
2. Or, the mouse "wraps" around the screen. Meaning, when the user reaches one edge of the screen, the mouse would simply continue on to the other side of the screen. (see: http://www.digicowsoftware.com/detail?_app=Wraparound) However, it appears that this too is not an inherent capability of javascript, but instead is only something a third party program could solve.

So, does the problem make sense? If so, is there any way I can implement the above solutions, or is there another one I'm missing?

Comment: Interesting question. Never underestimate F11, full-screen viewing that is. :-)

Comment: @zourtney Full-screen doesn't solve the problem because of: 1) The mouse gets capped at the screen bounds; 2) with a multimonitor setting the mouse can get off the browser area. Check my response down there.

Comment: @Chiguireitor, yes, I realize full screen alone is insufficient for a proper FPS for the reasons your mention. I didn't realize there was a draft spec for this. Thanks for teaching me something today. Your answer has my upvote :-) I think we all agree this type of requirement will only get *more* popular as web tech becomes more prevalent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anybody that still interested in achieving this, it is now somewhat available.

Using:

```
document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', changeCallback, false);
```

see example http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/

Comment: Yeah! API is also described here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/mouse-lock

Answer (score 4):

The worldwide community is currently working on a draft spec to solve this issue. What you're stating is called "mouse-locking". I've worked a little on the first phase of this standard to help lay out what's needed. Please, vote for these issues and subscribe to the indicated mail lists in order for all of us to get this issue corrected ASAP.

- Chromium Bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72754
- Firefox Bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633602
- W3C Mail list: http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=9557
- Draft proposal: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uV4uDVIe9-8XdVndW8nNGWBfqn9ieeop-5TRfScOG_o/edit?hl=es&authkey=CM-dw7QG

However, there's still a way you can achieve your objective (which is the other way i found): A native plugin that takes control of the mouse.

(I'm making a game too which is a FPS but currently won't be released due to this limitation)

Comment: Didn't realize there's an actual term for it. Thanks for the info! I'll be sure to pitch in.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about all of this. Standards-based web tech isn't going to give you mouse capturing like you want.

That said: you might be able to craft (or find) a special SWF that can collect mouse movement data and pass that to javascript. It won't constrain cursor movement, although you can use CSS to conceal the cursor while mouse capturing is active. But it might be able to e.g. continue firing "move mouse left" events even when the cursor has reached the left edge of the screen.

Any such SWF will probably fail to capture movement when the cursor is outside the viewport i.e. over the browser chrome.

Comment: Urgh. Although that might work, I feel like having a SWF overlay a WebGL script would be slow and difficult to implement. I appreciate the feedback, though.

Comment: The SWF wouldn't necessarily be an overlay. Similar to how it's possible to embed an invisible (or 1x1px) SWF to e.g. play audio resources, this SWF might be able to provide mouse movement data simply by being on the page -- regardless of whether the mouse is over the SWF or not. You'd need to ask some Flash people about this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's apparently not possible to do this as such in HTML5/Javascript, what about this variant: treat the mouse *position* (not mouse movement) as representing the rate of turning.

So if the mouse is more than a certain threshold left of the center, the camera turns left; the farther left the mouse is, the faster the camera turns. To stop turning, the player moves the mouse back toward the center.

To me this is an annoying UI, at least initially, but maybe the player would get used to it. Since we don't have any perfect solutions, it may be worth trying. You can mitigate the problem by allowing the arrow keys to work the way they do in many FPSes, rotating the camera when they are pressed down.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, although I think you're right. That UI could get frustrating. I might just go with arrow keys.